# How to cut variables which are beteween quotes from a string

Tags: bash, unix

I had problem with cut variables from string in " quotes. I have some scripts to write for my sys classes, I had a problem with a script in which I had to read input from the user in the form of (a="var1", b="var2")

I tried the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
read input
a=$($input | cut -d '"' -f3)
echo $a
```

it returns me a error "not found a command" on line 3 I tried to double brackets like

```
a=$(($input | cut -d '"' -f3)
```

but it's still wrong.

Comment: What are you expecting `a` and `b` to be? In most cases, Bash will handle the dequoting for you delivering the string inside.

Comment: im expecting it as int, i have to display sum and diffrenece of those

Comment: To clarify, with the string input `'var1'` you are expecting `a` to be assigned the integer value of `1`? If so, you need to use a regex or Bash string manipulation. Please clarify.

Comment: Try `a=$( echo $input | cut -d '"' -f3)`.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sory my english is not good, i mean that the user input is for example a="10", b="15" and i need to cut (in this example) 10 and 15 from this string

Comment: `awk -F\" '{print $2+$4}' <<< "$input"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment the OP gave a working answer (should post it as an answer):

```
#!/bin/bash
read input
a=$(echo $input | cut -d '"' -f2)
b=$(echo $input | cut -d '"' -f4)
echo sum: $(( a + b))
echo difference: $(( a - b))
```

This will work for user input that is exactly like `a="8", b="5"`.
Never trust input.
You might want to add the check

```
if [[ ${input} =~ ^[a-z]+=\"[0-9]+\",\ [a-z]+=\"[0-9]+\"$ ]]; then
   echo "Use your code"
else
   echo "Incorrect input"
fi
```

And when you add a check, you might want to execute the input (after replacing the comma with a semicolon).

```
input='testa="8", testb="5"'
if [[ ${input} =~ ^[a-z]+=\"[0-9]+\",\ [a-z]+=\"[0-9]+\"$ ]];
then
   eval $(tr "," ";" <<< ${input})
   set | grep -E "^test[ab]="
else
   echo no
fi
```

EDIT:
@PesaThe commented correctly about `BASH_REMATCH`:
When you use bash and a test on the input you can use

```
if [[ ${input} =~ ^[a-z]+=\"([0-9]+)\",\ [a-z]+=\"([0-9])+\"$ ]];
then
   a="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
   b="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

Comment: That's some...creative stuff, so to speak :) OP doesn't actually need to set the variables so the `eval` / `set` hell is not necessary. You could simply use `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: Sorry i'm new in posting here, next time ill try be better. Thank you for your solution, i sended mine already. Next time ill be aware of input check

Answer (score 0):

To extract the digit `1` from a string `"var1"` you would use a Bash substring replacement most likely:

```
$ s="var1"
$ echo "${s//[^0-9]/}"
1
```

Or,

```
$ a="${s//[^0-9]/}"
$ echo "$a"
1
```

This works by replacing any non digits in a string with nothing. Which works in your example with a single number field in the string but may not be what you need if you have multiple number fields:

```
$ s2="1 and a 2 and 3"
$ echo "${s2//[^0-9]/}"
123
```

In this case, you would use `sed` or `grep` `awk` or a Bash regex to capture the individual number fields and keep them distinct:

```
$ echo "$s2" | grep -o -E '[[:digit:]]+'
1
2
3
```

Comment: ``#!/bin/bash
    read input
    a=$(echo $input | cut -d '"' -f2)
    b=$(echo $input | cut -d '"' -f4)
    echo sum: $(( a + b))
    echo difference: $(( a - b))``

Comment: that is what i expected, thank u all guys for ur help